# Launch command at boot

Tags: boot, bootloader, fstab, wget

I have a computer, used as a server, running Xubuntu 16.04, and I want to launch a script (that uses *wget* , so it needs an internet connection), and I want this to happen before media partitions be mounted using fstab / crypttab.

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: I deleted my previous answer because I was missing your point. Can you explain why `wget` can only be run partitions are mounted? Perhaps you can simply describe the problem without proposing the solution.

Comment: Hello. Actually, my problem is to make sure that one partition will only be mounted after the script that calls wget is executed properly. How do I do that ?